# Laravel install fails on swiftmailer

Tags: php, git, laravel, composer-php, installation

I have not used Laravel in a while and have come to create a new project.

Whatever way I try to create a new project, whether through the installer, composer or even the repository it breaks on the SwiftMailer install (see console below)

*It does say within the error that the swiftmailer folder already exists but this is created during the install, it appears to be creating it twice, I have deleted the entire vendor folder and re-run the install and it still persists*

I have reinstalled composer / laravel and am on latest windows 10,

- Installing egulias/email-validator (2.1.3): Downloading (100%)
- Installing swiftmailer/swiftmailer (v6.0.2): Downloading (100%)
  Failed to download swiftmailer/swiftmailer from dist: The archive may contain identical file names with different capitalization (which fails on case insensitive filesystems): ZipArchive::extractTo(C:\Users\user\Desktop\Client\Client/vendor/composer/05707284/swiftmailer-swiftmailer-4123333\tests\acceptance\Swift\Transport\StreamBuffer/AbstractStreamBufferAcceptanceTest.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
  Now trying to download from source
- Installing swiftmailer/swiftmailer (v6.0.2): Cloning 412333372f from cache

  [RuntimeException]
  Failed to clone https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer.git via https, ssh protocols, aborting.
- https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer.git
  fatal: destination path 'C:\Users\user\Client\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer' already exists and is not an empty directory.
- git@github.com:swiftmailer/swiftmailer.git
  fatal: destination path 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\Client\Client\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer' already exists and is not an empty directory.

I have searched all over and I cannot find a solution, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The error is pretty clear... `'C:\Users\user\Client\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer' already exists and is not an empty directory.`

Comment: It appears to be creating the directory twice which I have noticed in the error message, but I have tried deleting the directory and reinstalling but it still throws the error

Answer (score 0):

To create a Laravel Project yu just have to use 2 commands :

> composer global require "laravel/installer"

and

> laravel new Project-Name

Or if yu want just use Composer :

> composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel Project-name

I hope I helped you.

Comment: Hi Yan, thanks for the reply, I have tried all those methods but the install breaks when it tries to install the SwiftMailer dependency and I cannot figure out why